# Using one Lambda function to handle multiple intent

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I have 4 intents in my Lex bot , logic of these intents is very similar with slight change in business rules

Is it a good practice to implement one lambda function and based on different intent you can call different functions ?

Can this approach introduce any potential bottle neck or performance impact ?

Answer (score 1):

There are no issues in using a single Lambda function for different intents. You can just call a single lambda function in all the intents, check the intent in that lambda and call relevant function/method in same lambda.

As you told, intents are very similar, so you could probably also use common functions for doing similar things for those intents.

```
def common_function():
    # some processing
    return cm

def intent2(intent_request):
    cm = common_function()
    # rest processing
    return output

def intent1(intent_request):
    cm = common_function()
    # rest processing
    return output

def dispatch(intent_request):
    logger.debug('dispatch userId={}, intentName={}'.format(intent_request['userId'], intent_request['currentIntent']['name']))
    intent_name = intent_request['currentIntent']['name']
    if intent_name == 'intent1':
        return intent1(intent_request)
    if intent_name == 'intent2':
        return intent2(intent_request)
    if intent_name == 'intent3':
        return intent3(intent_request)
    if intent_name == 'intent4':
        return intent4(intent_request)
    raise Exception('Intent with name ' + intent_name + ' not supported')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    logger.debug(event)
    logger.debug('event.bot.name={}'.format(event['bot']['name']))
    return dispatch(event)
```